Prove that continuous symmetric derivative has a point at which is is greater than zero
I need to prove the following Lemma, however my profesor were somewhat cofused and raised questions about this proof.
Let $f$ be continues function on the interval $[a,b]$ and $f$ be symmetricaly differentiable (note below) on $(a,b)$ and $f(a) < f(b)$ then there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f^*(c) \geqslant 0$
Note that the $f^*(x)$ is defined as followed
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}
$$
Here is a proof that I found in the article"Quasi-Mean Value Theorems for
Symmetrically Differentiable Functions"
Proof. Suppose $f(b) > f(a)$. Let $k$ be a real number such that $f(a) < k < f(b)$. The set
$\{x ∈ [a, b] | f(x) > k\}$ is bounded from below by $a$. Since it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ it has a greatest lower bound, say, $z$. Since $f$ is continuous and $k$ satisfies $f(a) < k < f(b)$, therefore
$z$ is different from $a$ and $b$. Let $(z - h, z + h)$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $z$ in $[a, b]$. Since $z$ is the greatest lower bound of the set $\{x ∈ [a, b] | f(x) > k\}$, there are points in $(z − h, z + h)$ such that $f(x + h) > k$ and $f(x − h) ≤ k$. Therefore
$$
f^*(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h) - f(z-h)}{2h} \geqslant 0
$$
why is that that the whole limit is $\geqslant 0$. I understand only that the numerator has such a property.

The key here is that the numerator is positive for any sufficiently small positive $h$. So inequality remains true in the limit as well.
